# ULR Reference in latex appear fist

Tags: bibtex, thesis, ref

The right position of my reference must appear as [1], but it appears [4].
And the reference of URL online appears as [1]
my bibtex file ordered as appearance
and bibliography style is {unsrt}.

Comment: Without an MWE what is being asked has a lack of context.

Comment: I think I can speak for the majority of people who frequent this site when I confess that my psychic abilities are utterly worthless: unless you provide a lot more information about you're doing and are trying to achieve, chances that I will somehow be able to guess correctly what's going on in your document are negligibly small.